# How do I use the information in a cell as the name of the sheet where an index formula is looking up the information from?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells

Ok I am creating a tracker of information and need to quickly copy and paste formulas since the criteria will be the same but the sheet as to which to look for the results will be different.

in cell `D3` (of the main sheet) I have the formula

```
=INDEX('0308B'!$R$3:$R$50,MATCH(1,($A3='0308B'!$L$3:$L$50)*($B3='0308B'!$M$3:$M$50),0))
```

This is returning the correct information...but I want to replace `'0308B'` with a formula as the name of the sheet `0308B` is in cell `C1` (of the main sheet).  I want to do this as each day I will have data on a different sheet, but will need to use the same lookup criteria each time and don't want to have to type in the new sheet name every time.

Comment: Try using the `INDIRECT` function.  Eg for your first array, replace with `INDIRECT("'" & C1 & "'!r3:r50")`.  Similarly with the others except for the obvious changes.

Comment: If you want a detailed explanation of using the INDIRECT function see here `https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-worksheet-reference`. Do note that INDIRECT is a volatile function, meaning it will recalculate with any and all changes to the workbook (unlike other functions that only recalculate if their inputs change). Volatile functions like RAND, NOW and INDIRECT can slow down you workbook, especially with large workbooks.